# Projecting from custom spatial reference?

Tags: coordinate-system

I have a shapefile with a WKT spatial reference below:

```
PROJCS["Prj_suplic",GEOGCS["Geo_suplic",DATUM["",SPHEROID["",1.0,0.0]],PRIMEM["",0.0],UNIT["",1.0]],PROJECTION["Aitoff"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

How can I project from it to another standard spatial reference such as epsg:3857?

### details

the data and spatial reference comes from this website
.

I can export arcgis json file from this website, however,when i try to converse it to a shpaefile through `ArcMap -> ArcToolbox -> Conversion Tools -> JSON TO Features`, it fail. A error message" coordinates out of bounds" showed. Although I search on the google .It seems that no one has faced a problem like that.

In order to make sure that the problem is lead by the spatial reference.Firstly, I create a custom spatial reference the same as it in the arcgis. Secondly, I created a shapefile with this spatial reference, and add some features to it. Thirdly, I export the shapefile to json with the `json to features` tool. In the end, I try to convert the output json file back to shp and it fail and show the same error message.

So can any one give me some solutions. It won't be restricted to projecting. Any other solution that can adjust the data to  normal position is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What GIS software are you using?

Comment: The `Aitoff` projection is covered by PROJ.4, but not GDAL. Hence you can **NOT** reproject using the standard GDAL tools. One reason is that there is no implementation of the inverse projection. Apart from that, your spheroid parameters make no sense in real world dimensions.

Comment: @PolyGeo the GIS software is not important, i can use any tool which can solve my problem.

Comment: @AndreJ thank you for your response. As you said _the spheroid parameters make no sense in real world dimensions_. But it is a real spatial reference showing on this website [bcode_pg](http://61.144.226.44:6080/arcgis/rest/services/msmap/bcode_pg/MapServer/0). I think maybe there is some encryption on there. So, my question is whether there is a way to transform it to a real world spatial reference.

Comment: `SPHEROID["",1.0,0.0]` Your spheroid is only one meter? I'm not sure that maps too well to the real world. Can you give us some sample coordinates with a general idea where it should be on the earth?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the coordinate reference system is correct. it's on a sphere of radius=1m while the units are equivalent to radians. When I try to unproject the reported extent values from the website to radians, and then to decimal degrees, I get an extent that covers most of the world. Here's the input and output values (in radians):

```
   Esri Projection Engine version 10.5.1.7203
   84433.24213013862 9814.51376415799
   171427.5913951584 53914.07924522892
   84433.24213013862 53914.07924522892
   171427.5913951584 9814.51376415799

   2.047708176973035       0.1960157648041461
   0.2740195567333302      0.08569952216737914
  -2.106671846975123       0.8374317581680009
  -1.102894630172711      -0.05991882886180464
```

The first output pair, converted to degrees, is at 11N, 117E. So there is likely some other obfuscation going on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I agree on that there is some obfuscation.I want to know that can i just move the features to match with another spatial reference. if can, which tool i can use to finish this job.